# Having a different StreamBuilder for every tab in TabBarView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a home page that has 3 tabs: Friends, Groups and Events.
After finally managing to load events for the current user only, I realised ill have a hard time loading different data for each tab - as the StreamBuilder stream: will always be the same for all the tabs.

I need help finding a way to have a different StreamBuilder for each of my tabs.
Code below:

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: _streamer(),//Firestore.instance.collection("Events").snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
                return new SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 42 - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom -AppBar().preferredSize.height - kToolbarHeight,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: TabBarView(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                child: ListView.separated(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                      _buildListItem(context,
                                          snapshot.data[index]),
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Divider();
                                  },
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: ListView.separated(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                      _buildListItem(context,
                                          snapshot.data[index]),
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Divider();
                                  },
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: ListView.separated(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                      _buildListItem(context,
                                          snapshot.data[index]),
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Divider();
                                  },
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ));
              },
            )
```

[This is how the home page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S44R.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're loading all data required for all your tabs using that stream. What you could do is have distinct pairs of stream/`StreamBuilder` for each tab:

```
... // widgets leading up to the TabBarView
TabBarView(
  controller: _controller,
  children: <Widget>[
    StreamBuilder(
          stream: friendsStream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SomeData> snapshot)  {
            return FriendsWidget();
          }
   ),
   StreamBuilder(
          stream: groupsStream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SomeData> snapshot)  {
            return GroupsWidget();
          }
   ),

//... etc
  ]
)
```

You could also wrap ONLY the widgets that should be rebuilt with a `StreamBuilder` instead of wrapping the whole parent widget:

```
... // widgets leading up to the TabBarView
TabBarView(
  controller: _controller,
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         SomeWidget(),
         AnotherWidget(),
         StreamBuilder(
           stream: friendsStream,
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SomeData> snapshot)  {
             return FriendsWidget();
           }
        )
      ]
    ),
// ... etc
  ]
)
```

If you are compelled to load all your data from the database at once, you could use a `Repository` class to load and store all your data, and then, depending on your architecture, have streams built from that class.

As a side note, I highly recommend using a `Bloc` with `BlocBuilder`. `Blocs` are just far superior to other designs (in most cases). [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) is my favorite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would i go on about changing my design to using blocs? And why are they superior?

Comment: @ShlomiLevush They provide a very elegant and intent-specific way to managing your app's state. [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern) is a very good application of the bloc pattern. There are a lot of other articles/examples out there if you want to know more.